How to find usages of dot separated string resource keys in Android?
In my team we have the same string resource keys for iOS and Android. The (long ago) agreed convention has dots in the key. For example:
<string name="menu.button.unlock">Unlock</string>

When I try to use the key in code, Android Studio doesn't find it and I have to type the key with underscores instead of dots. I understand that the compiler, under the hood, changes dots to underscores because of: Another Stackoverflow post
That's not a huge issue. The bigger issue is I cannot use "Find Usages" function in Android Studio on the string resources because it doesn't find them when the strings are referenced in code (and therefore with dots replaced as underscores).
Is there any way of getting around this issue to be able to use "Find Usages" without actually changing the convention?
Team is reluctant to change the convention, but it's a pain to not be able to find string usages.
